# Kendo data mapping in the spring controller

Tags: java, spring, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In Kendo before post the data, i can see the value as below,

```
{"models":[{"id":1,"publisherName":"Srini","active":false}]}
```

you can see the mapping done in the controller to Map collection. How can map the data from httprequest to model class Publisher?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/updatePublisher.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public void updatePublisher(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    Map<String, Object> data = Collections.emptyMap();

    if (0 < request.getContentLength()) {
        data = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), Map.class);
    }
    logger.debug("updatePublisher data: "+data);   // output : {models=[{id=1, publisherName=Srinisdasadsa, active=false}]}

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
}
```

### Java model object

```
public class Publisher {
    int id;
    String publisherName;
    boolean active;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getPublisherName() {
        return publisherName;
    }
    public void setPublisherName(String publisherName) {
        this.publisherName = publisherName;
    }
    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }
    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the [Kendo UI demo](http://demos.telerik.com/jsp-ui/grid/editing) is doing it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editing/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody List<Product> update(@RequestBody ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> models) 
{
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();

        for (Map<String, Object> model : models) {
            Product product = new Product();

            product.setProductId((int)model.get("productId"));
            product.setProductName((String)model.get("productName"));
            product.setUnitPrice(Double.parseDouble(model.get("unitPrice").toString()));
            product.setUnitsInStock((int)model.get("unitsInStock"));
            product.setDiscontinued((boolean)model.get("discontinued"));
            product.setCategoryId((int)model.get("categoryId"));

            products.add(product);
        }

        product.saveOrUpdate(products);

        return products;
}
```